# Rails with Devise - Login form partial redirects on bad login, logout doesn't reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, authentication, redirect, devise

I'm currently working on customizing Devise for my own web app.
I'm running into a couple problems with logging in and logging out.

---

*Problem #1:*

I've changed the devise/sessions/new.html.erb view to a custom form and turned it into a partial, _new.html.erb

**_new.html.erb**

```
<br/><br/>

<h3 id="login-box-label">Sign in here:</h3>
<br/>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :login, "Login:", class: "login-label" %>
    <%= f.text_field :login, autofocus: true, class: "login-input" %>
    <br/><br/>

    <%= f.label :password, "Password:", class: "login-label" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "login-input" %>
    <br/><br/>

    <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "login-button" %>
<% end %>
```

I'm rendering this partial on the homepage. It works great when the credentials entered are correct, but when the credentials entered are incorrect, instead of displaying an error, the form submission redirects the user to the regular /devise/sessions/new.html.erb, where the error is shown. I want to avoid this page entirely. Why is it redirecting here, and how can I stop that and make the errors show up in the div in which I'm rendering the partial?

---

*Problem #2:*

This may seem like a small issue, but it's not what I want to have happen. When I click my site's Logout button when I'm logged in, I've told the application controller:

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(user)
    root_path
end
```

Additionally, here is my logout button:

`<%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, remote: true, method: "delete", class: "logged-button", id: "logout" %>`

However, when I log out from the homepage, the logout is successful, but the homepage doesn't actually reload - it doesn't even turbolink, I assume because it's the same page. I need the page to refresh so that the control panel/logout buttons turn into a login button. What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I've generated the user session controller for Devise, as suggested by Gokul L, and it looks like this:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
# before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  # def create
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  # protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_sign_in_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:attribute])
  # end
end
```

What bits do I need to add here to get the desired behavior?

Comment: this is default implementation of devise,where it redirects to new page if login details are incorrect,...however..can you share sessions_controller.rb

Comment: My sessions_controller.rb is basically the same as before I added Devise. So it doesn't have anything to do with Devise at the moment

Comment: Generate the devise session_controller in your `app/controllers` folder and then try..

Comment: @GokulM Added the generated code with an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Remove comments from `create` and `new` action of the `sessions_controller` and then add then also generate the `devise views` in your `app/views`.

Add routes:

```
devise_for :user ,
            :controllers  => {
                :sessions => 'user/sessions'
            }
```

So, it now redirects to your views in app directory not to devise.

Then, you can do whatever you need.

You can add this line `<%= devise_error_messages! %>` in your form to get error messages..

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <%= f.label :login, "Login:", class: "login-label" %>

    ###
    ### Other codes
<% end %>
```

If you need to render other than `default view` you can specify a `layout` for those action.

Comment: I have generated the devise views, and moved the session views into users/sessions/_new.html.erb, but when I submit the form, it still tries to go to localhost:3000/users/sign_in

Comment: Yes, there it goes. Where you want it to go?

Comment: I want the login to happen on the same page until successful, using remote AJAX instead of actually visiting the sign in page. I have the partial form on my homepage and would rather it not direct to some other form elsewhere in the site after an incorrect attempt.

Comment: See my updated answer you can specify your layout for those action.

Comment: It's basically working now. The only thing left to do is redirect the devise_error_messages so I can update the contents of a div with them every time I click the login button. Would this be something I would do in the create action?

Comment: Realized I should've added this to my comment after it was too late to edit: My login now works with Ajax, but all I need is to return the flash[:notice] and flash[:alert] as a response to the Ajax call, whether it's with a respond_do |format| or other method.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out. (minus the AJAX notifications part)

**my updated, overriden session controller:**

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:control_panel]

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end

  def destroy
    super
  end

  def control_panel
    # Control panel page
  end

end
```

I also put my login form partial in the views/sessions directory, and removed the original devise sessions_controller.rb and the associated new.html.erb view.

Removing the `remote: true` parameter from my logout link allowed the page to refresh upon logout, updating the buttons and such things.